# Why won't JFileChooser close?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

The code below runs a method called *displayClassSet()*. I placed it in a do/while to recreate the error, which is JFileChooser doesn't close. When the do/while does not exist, it works fine. In the original code (over 700 lines) it gets to this method by using a switch. So, the user selects an option that executes *displayClassSet()*. Once it is done, it returns to the menu. At this point the JFileChooser stays open and won't allow any new menu choices. I hope I am being clear enough. I thought this would be better than trying to dump a huge file here. In the example code I have pasted below, if you select "n" once you return, it hangs. If you select "y" it closes, but again, the user may not be done in the original code. They can't because of the hanging issue I mentioned. I have also included a sample of the TXT file it is meant to open.

I have tried: `bufRdr.close();` and `in.close();`. I have also read several websites on JFileChooser.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class TestingArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        boolean done = false;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            displayClassSet();
            done = getYNConfirm(console, "Done?");
        } while (!done);

    }

    public static Boolean getYNConfirm(Scanner pipe, String prompt)
    {
        Boolean result = false;
        String input = "";
        String trash = "";

        do {
            System.out.print(prompt + " [y/n] ");
            if (pipe.hasNextDouble()) {
                trash = pipe.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Error: You entered \"" + trash + "\", Try again.");
            } else {
                input = pipe.nextLine();
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                    result = true;
                } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
        return result;
    }

    static void displayClassSet() throws IOException
    {
        File classFile = new File("/");
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        //int columnLength = 0;
        //Scanner inFile;
        int lineCount = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int charCount = 0;
        int countColumns = 0;
        int maxLineLength = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int high = 0;
        int low = 100;
        String line;
        Scanner in;

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

        try {
            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                classFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                in = new Scanner(classFile);
                while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                    line = in.nextLine();
                    lineCount++; // Same as lineCount = lineCount + 1;
                    charCount += line.length();
                    wordCount += countWords(line);
                    countColumns += countColumns(line);
                    int columnOneWidth = 25;
                    int gradeColumnWidth = 10;
                    maxLineLength = columnOneWidth + (((countColumns / lineCount + 2)) * gradeColumnWidth);
                }

                String[][] data = new String[lineCount][countColumns / lineCount];

                BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(classFile));

                //read each line of text file
                while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null && row < lineCount) {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        //get next token and store it in the array
                        data[row][col] = st.nextToken();
                        col++;
                    }
                    col = 0;
                    row++;
                }
                bufRdr.close();
                in.close();
                // CODE REMOVED - SIMPLE FOR LOOPS TO DISPLAY INFORMATION
                System.out.println("display stuff here...");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You must choose a file.\nReturn to the menu.");
                return;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: Could not open class file!");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
            System.out.println("IO ERROR trying to read file!");
            return;
        }
    }

    static int countWords(String in) {
        String trim = in.trim();

        if (trim.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return trim.split("\\s+").length; //separate string around spaces
    }

    static int countColumns(String in) {
        String trim = in.trim();

        if (trim.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return trim.split(",").length; //separate string around spaces
    }
}
```

**TEXT FILE CONTAINS:**

```
2nd Grade Pyromancy, Lab01, Quiz01, Test01
Ferrel Quinn, 75, 70, 80
Billy Brago, 70, 80, 90
Sally Simpson, 50, 60, 60
Django Rude, 100, 90, 90
```

Comment: Can you make the code a bit shorter? See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I made it as short as I can here. displayClassSet() is the focus. The rest supports to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own form made a button and added an action event listener to the button. 
I slightly modified the code from your post with this.  With this I was able to go back to the original form with out any problems.
These are the only changes to the code for the displayClassSet() function I made no modifications to any other code provided in the question.

```
File classFile;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
//int columnLength = 0;
//Scanner inFile;
int lineCount = 0;
int wordCount = 0;
int charCount = 0;
int countColumns = 0;
int maxLineLength = 0;
int sum = 0;
int high = 0;
int low = 100;
String line;
Scanner in;

File workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));//I only added this so as to 
//know the directory being used and would not have to search for it.
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(workingDirectory);
```

I moved the showOpenDialog and  classFile declarations out of the try/catch statement

```
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
{
    classFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    try 
    {
        in = new Scanner(classFile);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            line = in.nextLine();
            lineCount++; // Same as lineCount = lineCount + 1;
            charCount += line.length();
            wordCount += countWords(line);
            countColumns += countColumns(line);
            int columnOneWidth = 25;
            int gradeColumnWidth = 10;
            maxLineLength = columnOneWidth + (((countColumns / lineCount + 2)) * gradeColumnWidth);
        }
    }
```

I separated the try/catch statements for each different file opening usage

```
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Could not open class file!");
        System.exit(0);
    }             
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.getStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IO ERROR trying to read file!");
       //return;
    }

    String[][] data = new String[lineCount][countColumns / lineCount];
    try
    {
        BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(classFile));

        //read each line of text file
        while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null && row < lineCount) 
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                //get next token and store it in the array
                data[row][col] = st.nextToken();
                col++;
            }
                col = 0;
                row++;
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Could not open class file!");
        System.exit(0);
    }             
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.getStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IO ERROR trying to read file!");
        //return;
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < lineCount; x++)//I added this to check the contents of data[][]
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < (countColumns / lineCount); y++)
        {
            System.out.print(data[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
} 
else 
{
    System.out.println("You must choose a file.\nReturn to the menu.");
    //return;
}
```

I hope this will help in solving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented all of the suggestions by David Coler (thank you so much for your time!). I still had my particular issue. I started commenting out absolutely everything and the problem persisted when the only thing that happened was opening a file. Long story short, I ran it on a PC and it does fine in every regard. I still think I can streamline my code, but there seems to be an issue with JFileChooser on Macs.